# Cannot understand remove() function

Tags: java, queue

I got this class, but I can't understand how does remove function work. Why it needs to be a class name (`Customer`) before `remove()`, and what does it mean `Customer customer = (Customer) customers.firstElement();`

Can you help me?

```
private java.util.Vector customers = new java.util.Vector();
Server server;

void insert(AbstractEvent customer){
    customers.addElement(customer);
}
/**
 * @return the first customer in the queue
 */
Customer remove() {
    Customer customer = (Customer) customers.firstElement();
    customers.removeElementAt(0);
          return customer;
}
int size() {
    return customers.size();
}
```

Comment: That class looks like it's from the 90's.

Comment: @Kayaman true that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Customer remove()
```

The `remove()` method returns an object of type `Customer`. That's what the class name before `remove()` means.

```
Customer customer = (Customer) customers.firstElement();
```

`customers.firstElement()` returns the first element of the `Vector` object referred by the `customers` variable. Since the type of `customers` is a raw type (i.e. it doesn't specify the type of elements stored in the `Vector`), `firstElement()` returns an object of type `Object`, which must be cast to type `Customer` in order to be assigned to a `Customer` variable.

Replacing

```
private java.util.Vector customers = new java.util.Vector();
```

with

```
private java.util.Vector<Customer> customers = new java.util.Vector<>();
```

would allow to simply assign the first element of the Vector without casting :

```
Customer customer = customers.firstElement();
```